# Why does my magic mouse lose the connection when I lift and place down again on surface?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mouse

I have a magic mouse with 100% battery level indicator and am recently finding (since I changed the batteries) that when I raise the mouse off the surface and move to get more room for a motion and when I place it back down, it now often loses the connection.

Is there a loose connection in my mouse that is getting jostled when I place it back down again?
Is there something wrong with the new batteries?
Please suggest how to get a reliable bluetooth connection to my MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be about the batteries but for what I've experienced so far it's not about energy, but about their length, at a very slight scale.

Since two days I had this problem again - it occured like almost 10 times this morning. So I removed the battery cover, and put a flat piece of folded paper towel upon the batteries, in a way that when I put the cover back again, it is slightly bent, just what it needs to ensure a firm pressure on the batteries, so they won't move at all.

My conclusion is : problem solved.

**tl;dr** : you can fix Apple's 80$ mouse with 2 sheets of toilet paper

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem with the magic mouse connection being lost when I lifted the mouse.

I have now switched the batteries from my wife's magic mouse into my mouse and it works perfectly.

When I switch my batteries back into my mouse the problem comes back. The batteries are the exact same type (Energizer Advanced) as the ones in my wife's mouse.

At this point I thought that the issue lay with my batteries, until I switched my batteries into my wife's mouse and the mouse worked perfectly. So my batteries cause the problem in my mouse but not my wife's mouse.

So all I can suggest is that you get another pair of batteries and hope they work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and I tried adding the paper shim without success. What is working for me right now is leaving the cover off completely. So far so good but it is only day one.